# Datatable is not being populated

Tags: c#, sql-server

Attempting to populate a datatable with a SqlDatareader (I don't think I can use DataAdapter because of the way I am parsing a xml string). Just by looking at examples of datatables online this SHOULD work, but it doesn't. When I debug it table is always {} when it runs through the do while loop. What's the deal?

```
string sqlEntry = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlPass"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlEntry);

try
{
    conn.Open();
    conn.ChangeDatabase(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);

    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * from equipInspection";
    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

    SqlDataReader myReader;
    myReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    table.Columns.Add("Equipment", typeof(String));
    table.Columns.Add("SerialNo",typeof(String));
    table.Columns.Add("Contractor",typeof(String));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(String));
    table.Columns.Add("Deficiencies", typeof(String));

    if (myReader.Read())
    {
        do
        {
            string stringtosplit = myReader["formXML"].ToString();
            string[] xmlInfo = stringtosplit.Split(new string[] { ";ANKR!" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["Equipment"] = xmlInfo[0];
            row["SerialNo"] = xmlInfo[1];
            row["Contractor"] = myReader["Name"].ToString();
            row["Date"] = myReader["Date"].ToString();
            row["Deficiencies"] = xmlInfo[12];
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        } while (myReader.Read());
```

Here is a sample of the xml format. It may be the way it is structured or the way I am parsing it.

```
    <!--Equipment inspection form by Test-->
<EquipmentInspection Date="2013/08/07" Time="12:05 AM" Location="Somewhere" ContractorName="Joe" Operator="Jane" Position="Boss" Contact="2132213421">
  <Field ID="txtEquipment" Type="Textbox">Jackhammer;ANKR!</Field>
  <Field ID="txtSerial" Type="Textbox">1234A5A-1;ANKR!</Field>
  <Field ID="txtManufacturer" Type="Textbox">Test;ANKR!</Field>
  <Field ID="txtUsage" Type="Textbox">Test;ANKR!</Field>
  <Field ID="txtService" Type="Textbox">2013/08/05;ANKR!</Field>
  <Field ID="rblRecentInspect" Type="RadioButtonList">No;ANKR!</Field>
  <cblShift>2, ;ANKR!</cblShift>
  <cblDaysInspected>W, F, ;ANKR!</cblDaysInspected>
  <Field ID="rblDamage" Type="RadioButtonList">Yes;ANKR!</Field>
  <Field ID="txtDamage" Type="Textbox">;ANKR!</Field>
  <Field ID="txtRepairs" Type="RadioButtonList">No;ANKR!</Field>
  <Field ID="rblDef" Type="RadioButtonList">No;ANKR!</Field>
  <Field ID="txtDef" Type="Textbox">it broke;ANKR!</Field>
</EquipmentInspection>
```

Comment: Indeed that should really work. Are you sure you're looking at the table at the right time? Have you stepped through the loop and made sure it enters it?

Comment: What does the original string look like ("formXml") .. ?

Comment: Also, why do you have the main loop nested inside `if (myReader.Read())`? Is there more to the code that we aren't seeing? If not, you could just replace the `if` and the `do` with a `while`.

Comment: Post a sample of the XML, you can probably do this a lot cleaner  and better than splitting a string and parsing the values

Comment: if(myReader.Read()) will read the first entry and place the cursor on the second one. If you only have one entry, this won't work. Avoir the if and do a simple while(myReader.Read()) (not a do-while).

Comment: Where did you open the connection?

Comment: Are you sure you are not gettng any exception when you call `xmlInfo[...]`?

Comment: Agreed on using a while loop instead of do/while, generally speaking, but it shouldn't actually error out. He doesn't make a second Read() call until the while part of do-while, so the if statement starts the process, the do uses that first iteration, then the while will get called for subsequent rows. It's clean logic, but better stated with a while loop.

Comment: formXML is an xml file made from controls in a panel that were looped through. Here I will update with sample

Comment: updated with xml sample and *all* of the code (in page load)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you clicking the spyglass to look at the actual table? From a quick glance you seem to be doing everything right and if debugging isn't erroring out then you're almost certainly getting your data back just fine. The table isn't going to have the data until you add the row, of course. I know it sounds silly, but make sure you click the spyglass after at least one iteration of table.Rows.Add(row); ....

Comment: And let me be clear: click the spyglass. DataTable will always shows {} as its value in the locals list. You have to click the spyglass to SEE the data in the table....

Comment: table is being populated after all, haha. Well thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this excerpt from your code:

```
conn.Open();

conn.ChangeDatabase(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
```

The second line forces the connection closed again. Just swap the two lines and you should be fine.

Comment: I still don't know that's the specific issue; he should be seeing an error on the read call if the connection closed, but you're right that that should be fixed, so have some upvote... EDIT: NOOOOOPE, I just looked at that property (was new to me), and it says: "Changes the current database for an open SqlConnection." So it's opening a connection to a server then switching the database on the server, so the connection is open and stays open. Do not fix!